# Flask: Ubicación de imagen cambia

Tags: python, flask

Tengo una pequeña aplicación dónde subo una imagen y esta se guarda junto con el directorio, en una base de datos **sqlite**. La ubicación: `/static/imagenes/Cursos/imagen.jpg`.

Al usarla en una página pasando la variable `{{ Cursos.Imagen}}`, se muestra sin problemas:

```
<div class="row">
            {% for Cursos in Cursos %}
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <center>
                <img src="{{ Cursos.Imagen }}" width="200px">
                </center>
                <h3>{{ Cursos.Nombre }}</h3>
                <p>{{ Cursos.ResumenB }}</p>
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="/curso/{{ Cursos.ID }}">Ver información</a>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

Y en la terminal puedo ver que la petición `GET` es la ubicación correcta.
Sin embargo al querer mostrarla en otra página, la ubicación cambia a `/curso/static/imagenes/Cursos/imagen.jpg`.

La página dónde ocurre este error tiene el siguiente código:

```
{% for Cursos in Cursos %}
    <section class="cursos">
        <center>
            <h2>{{ Cursos.Nombre }}</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <center>
                        <img src="{{ Cursos.Imagen }}" width="400px">
                </center>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <center>
                    <h3>Descripción</h3>
                    <p>{{ Cursos.Resumen}}</p>
                    <h3>Fechas: {{ Cursos.Fechas }}</h3>
                    <p>Precio: {{ Cursos.Precio }}</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Contactar</a>
                </center>
            </div>
            </div>
        </center>
    </section>
    {% endfor %}
```

Este comportamiento se me hace curioso, pues todos los demás datos se muestran menos la imagen, cambiando la ubicación de la misma por algún motivo.

Si alguien pudiese orientarme en que es lo que esta causando esto le agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto pasa porque se está usando la dirección relativa de la página actual. Por ejemplo, si actualmente te encuentras en `/curso`:

```
<img src="{{ Cursos.Imagen }}" width="400px">
```

El resultado de la URL sería `/curso/static/imagenes/Cursos/imagen.jpg`. Si te encuentras en `/curso/1` entonces la URL sería `/curso/1/static/imagenes/Cursos/imagen.jpg`.

Si te das cuenta, se agrega a la URL actual al resultado de `Cursos.Imagen`. Lo que tienes que hacer es anteponer la raíz `/` cuando quieras mostrar la URL de tu imagen para indicar que quieres usar una URL absoluta:

```
<img src="/{{ Cursos.Imagen }}" width="400px">
```

O, en su defecto, implementar una función en tu modelo que se encargue de hacerlo.